# Can we restrict ssrs from creating extra columns while exporting to excel if they are row grouped

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can we restrict SSRS from creating extra columns while exporting to excel if they are row grouped?

SSRS Report

[image: SSRS REPORT IMG]

Output after exporting to excel
[image: output after exporting to excel]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the extra columns you're referring to are C and E. Those are created because you have other elements on the report that have edges at those points. For example, if you have a title textbox or other tables on the report. Make sure you align the edges of the cells and textboxes and that won't happen.

Comment: I didn't quite get the answer what you said can you elaborate your comment please..@StevenWhite

Comment: everything looks fine with the alignment i was wondering if my row grouping id causing me anything that creates extra columns...@StevenWhite

Comment: @SantoshKumarReddyBadugula include a screenshot of your whole report design and I'll point out the elements that aren't aligned.